# Updating firmware using the Azure IoT Hub

Tags: azure-iot-hub, intel-edison, azure-iot-sdk

I intend to use the IoT Hub to update firmware of my Edison device utilising its bi-directional capability although I am not sure of where to look for detailed instructions on how to do it. The only information I have found on the subject is [HERE](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/iot-hub-device-management/#remote-firmware-and-software-update) but doesn't go into detail on how exactly to do it, more a high level overview. Does anyone have any knowledge on how this is to be done or know any links that will help?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link you provided returns 404 for me right now; maybe that's temporary...

I work for Microsoft, on the Device Management SDK team for IoT Hub. The new Device Management capabilities we announced at Build last week should give you exactly what you need, but there isn't much info because the features aren't available to the public just yet.

For a preview, take a look at [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/B815) video from Build where we demo'd firmware update on the Intel Edison. The device management segment starts at about 35 min, demo at 40 min.

To do firmware update using only what's available publicly today in IoT Hub, you'd probably start by sending a [cloud-to-device message](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-c2d/) to your Edison. Of course, exactly how you go about downloading and updating the firmware after that is specific to your device and scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Damon, that explains the lack of documentation. I was hoping to really push the use of Azure IoT capability at my workplace (big energy) as I use it personally (and they don't really have a good solution as yet) but the remoteness of the where the devices would be used at work means the engineers questioned the ability to update firmware remotely. And I couldn't reply with an answer and neither could my friend Google... I hope something comes out shortly!

Comment: Thanks. This is currently confusing as heck :-) I may post a separate Q. What is the difference between firmware and an (uwp) app? And there is an oem-platform (free or not?) and oem-pro platform (for $) which have app update capabilities. Then there is the iot-hub-device-management stuff which seems to do much of the same. Please de-confuse us :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to the repo which allows you to update firmware remotely using the IoT Hub. Thanks MS!

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/tree/dmpreview

Comment: As of today, the github link returns 404 because branch/tag has been deleted.